# Typo3 GraphicMagick Thumbs transparent

Tags: typo3, imagehandler

Im working on a website using typo3 and the image handler being used is GraphicMagick. At an certain page im displaying an Latest view news item. 
This news item contains an media pdf file.

So when I visit that page I will see an Thumb of that pdf since that is being created by GraphicMagick and stored in my typo3temp folder.

Now the real question is.. that this gif file, is like 10-15% transparent at the top.

[image]

I have no idea how this comes.. the settings in the installation tool look similar to the onces I use on a different website.

Did anybody see this before and knows how I might resolve this ?

I'm using the following versions:
Typo3: 6.2.11
imagehandler: Graphics Magick

Answer (score 1):

[GFX][thumbnails_png] = 1

Solved it for me, gifs gave me a problem